# Android : How to pass an active Surface Object from one process to another process in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a media player kind of application in which my UI is a separate application where I am getting a surface object through surfaceHolder of a SurfaceView object.
Then I am trying to send it across to the process(another app) in which a Service is running so that i can extract the ISurface ptr from the surface and register the buffers with it and supply the data to displayed.

The problem here is that I am not able send the active surface object to the other process. The object is becoming invalid when I check it in the service side process.
Kindly let me know whether passing of active objects is possible and if yes please tell me how.

Comment: I've been trying it for a while now... with no luck unfortunately.

I think from Android 11 onward this might become possible, however: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/SurfaceControlViewHost